# Keep getting Uncaught TypeError

Tags: php

User 1 is Johnny. User 2 is Billy. Billy can follow Johnny but when Johnny tries to follow Billy, I get an error. I have looked at my code over and over but can not find the issue. Error that pops up is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_column(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\classes\post.classes.php:365 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\classes\post.classes.php(365): array_column(NULL, 'userid') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\like.php(33): Post->like_post('98168', 'user', '7500') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\index.php(23): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\classes\post.classes.php on line 365

```
public function follow_user($id,$type,$mfg_userid){

    if($id == $mfg_userid && $type == 'user'){
        return;
    }

    $DB = new Database();

    $sql = "select following from likes where type='$type' && contentid = '$mfg_userid' limit 1";

    $result = $DB->read($sql);

    if(is_array($result)) {

        $likes = json_decode($result[0]['following'],true);

        $user_ids = array_column($likes, "userid");

        if(!in_array($id, $user_ids)) {

            $arr["userid"] = $id;
            $arr["date"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            $likes[] = $arr;

            $likes_string = json_encode($likes);

            $sql = "update likes set following = '$likes_string' where type='$type' && contentid = '$mfg_userid' limit 1";
            $DB->save($sql);

            $user = new User();
            $single_post = $user->get_user($id);

            add_notification($_SESSION['mfg_userid'],"follow",$single_post);

        } else {

            $key = array_search($id, $user_ids);
            unset($likes[$key]);

            $likes_string = json_encode($likes);

            $sql = "update likes set following = '$likes_string' where type='$type' && contentid = '$mfg_userid' limit 1";
            $DB->save($sql);

        }
        
    } else {

        $arr["userid"] = $id;
        $arr["date"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $arr2[] = $arr;

        $following = json_encode($arr2);

        $sql = "insert into likes (type,contentid,following) values ('$type','$mfg_userid','$following')";
        $DB->save($sql);
        
        $user = new User();
        $single_post = $user->get_user($id);

        add_notification($_SESSION['mfg_userid'],"follow",$single_post);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the error is thrown at `array_column($likes, "userid");`? Check what `$likes` actually contains (which seems to be `null`). The reason for that is probably that `$result[0]['following']` doesn't contain valid json, or json that will convert into an array. Do some debugging, like check what `var_dump($result)` actually contains.

Comment: So I did var_dump after where it says if(is_array($result)) and got array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["following"]=> string(52) "[{"userid":"71341238","date":"2022-03-19 05:58:05"}]" }

Comment: And what did `$likes` contain after that? Add a `var_dump($likes)` as after your `json_deoce()` well. Can you also confirm that we're actually looking at the correct `array_column()` code (line `365` in the file `post.classes.php`)? And when it looks correct, do you then get that error?

Comment: Tbh, you should rather [normalize your database](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html) instead of adding relational data in a serialized form like that. It might feel like a lot of extra work when you start doing that, but it makes things like this _much_ easier and way less error prone. It's what the database is built for, after all.

Comment: Thats where things get confusing. So my follow_user function is under my user.classes.php so the one directing to post.classes.php would be for liking the post rather than following the user like I am wanting to do.

Comment: That didn't give me any answers to my questions.

Comment: This is what I get after var_dump $likes... 
array(0) { } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["following"]=> string(52) "[{"userid":"71341238","date":"2022-03-19 06:37:01"}]" }